# hide google analytic code

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, master-pages

Is it possible not to show the google analytic code on the master page? I mean can I place it somewhere where no one can see it but still get all the analysis on the application ?

Comment: As in hide it from viewing source? No, not really.

Comment: it's impossible to complete conceal it.. you could minimise it.. or merge it into existing external JS code..

Comment: @Lloyd yes it is possible to conceal it, you can call the code from the server using WebRequest with code that google provides.

Comment: @vcsjones Yes you can by make the call using WebRequest from original google sdk code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mobile code for google analytic to make what you ask.

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/

How this works. This google modile code can call the google analytic from your server on code behind, and not from the client page using javascript. So you can totally hide this call from your clients, and all data are send to google analytic, let say on page load.

First on your google analytic detail page, get the code for mobiles for asp.net, and then see this code that you need to focus and change, so you can make a global function that use on Page Load. To avoid possible delay I also suggest to make a new thread call to the google analytics, until the asp.net 4.5 get outs that include that option on WebRequest.

```
string utmGifLocation = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif";

        // Construct the gif hit url.
        string utmUrl = utmGifLocation + "?" +
            "utmwv=" + Version +
            "&utmn=" + GetRandomNumber() +
            "&utmhn=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(domainName) +
            "&utmr=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentReferer) +
            "&utmp=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentPath) +
            "&utmac=" + account +
            "&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B" +
            "&utmvid=" + visitorId +
            "&utmip=" + GetIP(GlobalContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

        SendRequestToGoogleAnalytics(utmUrl);



    private void SendRequestToGoogleAnalytics(string utmUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest connection = WebRequest.Create(utmUrl);

            ((HttpWebRequest)connection).UserAgent = GlobalContext.Request.UserAgent;
            connection.Headers.Add("Accepts-Language",
                GlobalContext.Request.Headers.Get("Accepts-Language"));

            using (WebResponse resp = connection.GetResponse())
            {
                // Ignore response
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (GlobalContext.Request.QueryString.Get("utmdebug") != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error contacting Google Analytics", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

All that is a little hack on google analytic mobile code, but the general idea works on your case. Get the Google Analytic SDK here.
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/home.html

What actually google try to archive here. Google say that there is not reason for mobile phone with limited and costly bandwidth to make the call on google analytics. So google make a code behind call to google analytic just by opening a page. From the part of the mobile, he only need to read a tiny image, and on code behind this call to the image is making the reall call to google. From your side, you do not need to place an image, you can direct call google analytic by changing a little the function that google provides.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

since you have to put it in your header for the analytic script, there is no easy way of doing this. you want to hide your ID#? There may be a way to reference a variable for your ID#, but without a bunch of extra coding there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

If it's there, people can see it if they look for it. If it's not there, you can't get the analysis.

You could get a little sneaky, and have the analytics on a page that gets loaded into an invisible iframe, but someone that wants to find it will.